# How can I restrict the options for ForeignKey to keys inside a ManyToMany field

Tags: django

I have a ManyToManyField that stores a users "inventory" which is a ManyToManyField of items, I also have a foreign key field "active" that stores the id of the active item of the user. I was wondering if there was a constraint I could put so that any "active" id must be in the ManyToMany inventory.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the save() method of the model and catch and handle possible non-compliance there.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: Thanks! but this works once the user is already created, but I'm getting "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used" when creating brand new users because I referencing the manytomany to validate the user items